# How to test weblogic cluster servers?

Tags: weblogic

I have created a cluster with 2 servers and I have developed a sample application. I can access this application from ip address of these servers(10.0.0.3:7002/sample/ and 10.0.0.4:7002/sample/) but I don't know this cluster is working or not. Can I access this web application from a single address? like myclusteraddress:7002/sample/.

Comment: Shouldn't there be a load balance point in front of the two handling this?

Comment: Like duffymo said, you'll need a load balancer/VIP to access it from a single address. You could also create a singleton service that only runs on one server in the cluster but that's overkill just to prove your cluster is up

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this task in two ways...

First Way

```
You need to create a Load balancer(F5) to the both the servers which automatically manages the traffic and serves the user requests...
```

Second Way

```
You have to a dns cutover for that website...it's same as above task almost.
```